# Relógio Javascript com horário NTP ou do servidor

Tags: javascript

Tenho o código abaixo, que exibe um relógio em uma página, que serve para registro de intervalos da fábrica. Ele funciona perfeitamente, com o código abaixo:

```
function moveRelogio(){

    momentoAtual = new Date();

    hora = momentoAtual.getHours();

    if (hora < 10) {
      hora = '0' + hora;
    } else {
      hora = hora + '';
    }

    minuto = momentoAtual.getMinutes();
    if (minuto < 10) {
      minuto = '0' + minuto;
    } else {
      minuto = minuto + '';
    }

    segundo = momentoAtual.getSeconds();
    if (segundo < 10) {
      segundo = '0' + segundo;
    } else {
      segundo = segundo + '';
    }

    horaImprimivel = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo

    document.cadastro.hora_inicio.value = horaImprimivel;

    setTimeout("moveRelogio()",1000);
}
```

Eventualmente o horário exibido não é o mesmo registrado, pois para registro é usado o horário do AD. O usuário não pode alterar ele, pois são usados PI sem teclado e mouse.

Existe alguma forma com Javascript para pegar o horário de um servidor ou da internet, de um NTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a mesma lógica do código que tinha, alterei o código e agora sim ele pega o horário do servidor que está hospedado o código. Funcionou perfeitamente:

```
<?php
//PEGA HORA ATUAL DO SERVIDOR
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT');
$hoje = getdate();
?>
<script>
    var d = new Date(Date.UTC(<?php echo $hoje['year'].",".$hoje['mon'].",".$hoje['mday'].",".$hoje['hours'].",".$hoje['minutes'].",".$hoje['seconds']; ?>));
    setInterval(function() {
        d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 1);
        //EXIBE O HORÁRIO COM 2 DIGITOS
        $('#hora_inicio').val((("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) +':' + ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +  ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2) ));
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

E no HTML:

```
      <tr>
          <td>Hora Atual:</td>
          <td><input type = "text" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; height: 40px; font-size: 30px;" readonly="true" id="hora_inicio" name = "hora_inicio" size = 12></td>
      </tr>
```

Final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Se você for utilizar um NTP, para uso empresarial, provavelmente terá que pagar uma licença.

Se você utiliza uma plataforma no servidor que lhe permita usar PHP, .NET, Java, Ruby etc. você pode montar um serviço que retorna os horários local e UTC.

Para consumir, seria algo como o código abaixo. Exemplo em jQuery pois suponho que você não seja masoquista:

```
var dt;
$.ajax({
    url: "http://enderecoDoSeuServico/",
    success: function (horario) {
        dt = new Date(horario);
    }
});
```

Para que isso aí funcione, basta que a variável `horario` seja a quantidade de milissegundos desde a hora zero de primeiro de janeiro de 1970 (no fuso horário de Greenwhich), que é o valor "zero" do tipo `Date` do Javascript. Por esse motivo, o código em .NET poderia ser algo como:

```
public long RetornaHorario()
{
    DateTime inicio = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1); // supondo fuso horário zero
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - inicio;
    return span.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Não deve ser muito diferente com as demais linguagens que você pode usar no servidor.

Lembre-se de que haverá uma latência entre a chamada e o retorno do serviço, então você terá que aceitar uma precisão de alguns milissegundos a alguns segundos dependendo do seu setup.

Comment: Ótima resposta Renan. Mas como não tinha tempo hábil para alterar muito a estrutura atual do código, acabei encontrando uma outra forma. Vou postar ela abaixo, com a base do código da pergunta. De qualquer forma, +1. Obrigado.